# Accessing properties of an object as parameters for a method

Tags: objective-c, object, methods

I am in the process of learning objective-c, so please forgive my ignorance. How could I use the properties of an object as parameters for an instance method for that object? For example, I created an object FamilyMember with two parameters, name, and preference(an enumeration). If I wanted to use those properties as parameters for the dinnerPrefMethod method, how would that be done. This is what I have so far, and as you can see, I would have to manually enter the person's preference if I wanted to call the method. My goal is to be able to call the method, and have it take the two properties of the object as parameters.

```
@implementation FamilyMember

@synthesize name, preference;


-(void) dinnerPrefMethod : (dinnerPreference) x; {
    NSLog(@"Lets see what %@ wants for dinner", name);
    switch( x )
{
    case pizza:
        NSLog(@"%@ wants pizza", name);
        break;
    case steak:
        NSLog(@"%@ wants steak", name);
        break;
    case seafood:
        NSLog(@"%@ wants seafood", name);
        break;
    case dunno:
        NSLog(@"%@ doesn't know", name);
        break;
}
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see you are using object's property in its method. In that case you need not have to pass those values as you can access them directly.

---

**Update**

```
-(void) dinnerPrefMethod {
    NSLog(@"Lets see what %@ wants for dinner", self.name);
    switch(self.preference)
    {
    case pizza:
        NSLog(@"%@ wants pizza", self.name);
        break;
    case steak:
        NSLog(@"%@ wants steak", self.name);
        break;
    case seafood:
        NSLog(@"%@ wants seafood", self.name);
        break;
    case dunno:
        NSLog(@"%@ doesn't know", self.name);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: So I can use the properties of an object in the method without saying that they are parameters?

Comment: Yes, only in instance method(means the method belongs to same class)

Comment: Thanks, but when I did that, I got an error on the line when I declare the switch statement that says "statement requires expression of integer type ('dinnerPreference' invalid)

Comment: Would you post the definition for your `dinnerPreference` enum?

Comment: Have you used `self.preference` ??

Comment: that line reads     `switch(self.preference)` and it's giving me an error

Comment: `typedef enum { pizza = 0, steak = 1, seafood = 2, dunno = 3 } dinnerPreference;`

Comment: could you post the `preference` declaration (@property)

Comment: `@property dinnerPreference *preference;`

Comment: use `@property dinnerPreference preference;` as dinnerPreference is not a class but enum so you don't need reference but variable

Answer (score 0):

> If I wanted to use those properties as parameters for the dinnerPrefMethod method, how would that be done.  [...]  My goal is to be able to call the method, and have it take the two properties of the object as parameters.

It sounds like you want to avoid doing all this:

```
FamilyMember *familyMember = [[FamilyMember alloc] init];
[familyMember setName:@"First Last"];
[familyMember setPreference:dunno];
[familyMember announceDinnerPreference];
```

where `-[FamilyMember announceDinnerPreference]` is a modified version of your `dinnerPrefMethod:`:

```
- (void)announceDinnerPreference
{
    NSLog(@"Let's see what %@ wants for dinner...", [self name]);
    switch ([self preference]) {
        case pizza:
            NSLog(@"%@ wants pizza.", [self name]);
            break;
        case steak:
            NSLog(@"%@ wants steak.", [self name]);
            break;
        case seafood:
            NSLog(@"%@ wants seafood.", [self name]);
            break;
        case dunno:
            NSLog(@"%@ doesn't know.", [self name]);
            break;
    }
}
```

Perhaps you want to define a method `-[FamilyMember setName:preference:announceDinnerPreference:]`

```
- (void)setName:(NSString *)name preference:(dinnerPreference)preference announceDinnerPreference:(BOOL)announce
{
    [self setName:name];
    [self setPreference:preference];
    if (announce) {
        [self announceDinnerPreference];
    }
}
```

This would allow you to write

```
FamilyMember *familyMember = [[FamilyMember alloc] init];
[familyMember setName:@"First Last" preference:dunno announceDinnerPreference:YES];
```

Frankly, though, this is very stylistically weird.

---

A much more stylish way approach would be to define `-initWithName:preference:`

```
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name preference:(dinnerPreference)preference
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setName:name];
        [self setPreference:preference];
    }
    return self;
}
```

You would then be able to write

```
FamilyMember *familyMember = [[FamilyMember alloc] initWithName:@"First Last" preference:dunno];
[familyMember announceDinnerPreference];
```

---

> So I can use the properties of an object in the method without saying that they are parameters?

Yes.  An object's instance variables are accessible within its instance methods.